# When should we perform fetching data from a remote server?

Tags: reactjs

If we had to fetch the comments from a remote server, when would we perform that action?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export class CommentBox extends Component {
  // ...

  _fetchComments() {
    //  it updates the component's state
  }

  // Voluntarily obfuscated
  componentXXX() {
    setInterval(() => this._fetchComments(), 5000);
  }

  render() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

If do you see any problem with the implementation above pls do suggest and I'll implement it. Thanks.

Comment: any lifecycle method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally we should perform side-effects(i.e asynchronous tasks or can say network requests) in `componentDidMount()` lifecycle **only if we want to affect the initial DOM tree** or can say that we forcefully want to update the DOM whenever data is available (as soon as possible) through fetching data from remote server.

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is mounted (inserted into the tree). Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request.

Code (If data is supposed to be in effect on initial mount as it will use `setState` to re-render) -

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
export class CommentBox extends Component {
    // ...

    _fetchComments() {
        // some AJAX request
        let data = null;
        // using promise to resolve the data
        ApiCall().then(responseJson => data = responseJson).catch(err => console.log(err))

        this.setState({data});
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        setInterval(() => this._fetchComments(), 5000);
    }

    render() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Otherwise it's totally okay to perform network request in any custom/user defined method on event you want to fire like `onClick` of any button or `onChange` for input and if you want to set that data into state, use `setState` to make sure the re-render happens to change the DOM tree

Comment: Is this the best way to use setInterval() to fetch data in production env?

Comment: No, you should remove `setInterval()` for production env. componentDidMount will automatically update the state **regardless** if you want to forcefully set time interval